# Efficiently detect a modified EXIF tag for an image that has the same visual data

Tags: python, imagemagick

How can I detect if only the EXIF tag for an image was modified, but the visual part of the file remains the same? I know Imagemagick has the "visual sum" feature which generates a hash for the visual part of an image, which I could then compare to the md5 hash, but this is really, really slow for large images. Is there a faster way?

Comment: Does it need to be a python script, or would a bash script also fit your needs?

Comment: Python is ideal, but bash would be ok. I'm more concerned with the ideology of how to do this efficiently, but sample code is always appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You could copy both files and then remove all the exif information with for example `jhead -de image1.jpg image2.jpg`. After that, you can simply compare the files with `diff image1.jpg image2.jpg`. Would that be efficient enough?